# Go r.PostForm is empty

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I tried to send form data and file to server but from the server the form value is empty , but i receive file only

**SERVER**

```
func CreatePost(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    createdAt := time.Now().String()
    r.ParseForm()
    data := r.PostForm.Get("body")
    fmt.Println(r.PostForm)
    r.ParseMultipartForm(10 << 20)
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
    ///Some Codes///////
}
```

**TERMINAL OUTPUT**

```
19:33:08 app         | listerning on 8080
19:33:11 app         | map[]
```

[image: CLICK ME]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the docs for `ParseForm`:

> For other HTTP methods, or when the Content-Type is not application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the request Body is not read, and r.PostForm is initialized to a non-nil, empty value.

When you submit a file, the content type will be one of the multipart types.

Based on these docs, I'd try this:

```
 r.ParseMultipartForm(10<<20)
 data := r.PostForm.Get("body")
 fmt.Println(r.PostForm)
 file, header, err := r.FormFile("file")
```

Comment: Thanks bro its working btw why should i do this? Can you please explain?

Comment: When you submit a file, the request type will be multipart/formdata, and the request will have multiple parts. One part will contain the form data, and other parts will contain the files. ParseMultiPart parses the form data and those files. PartForm only parses URL encoded form data.